# Dropdown Inside a Semantic-UI Sidebar

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I have a sidebar which basically functions as a secondary menu. Within this sidebar, I need to implement a dropdown which will show on top of the dimmed pushed content.

I am having trouble displaying the dropdown. Clicking on the dropdown ("Select Language") automatically closes the sidebar and no dropdown gets shown.

My JS looks like this:

```
$('.context.example .ui.sidebar')
  .sidebar({
    context: $('.context.example .bottom.segment'),
    transition: 'push'
  })
  .sidebar('attach events', '.context.example .menu .item')
;

$('ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

The full example is on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psychomachine/udLwnjh9/4/).

How can I make sure the sidebar doesn't close on click and the dropdown gets shown on top of the dimmed pushed content?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach sidebar action event to the top attached menu item rather than selecting all menu items. And initialize your dropdown as

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

Attach events to the top menu button,

```
$('.context.example .ui.sidebar')
   .sidebar('attach events', '.context.example .context.example .top.attached.menu .item')
```

Also add this style

```
.ui.sidebar {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nighisha/ds9tuozu/)